# Swift not printing to console with print() command, other code works fine

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode9

I am using `XCode Version 9.0 beta (9M136h)` to write an application with a watchkit extension.  I can get the application to communicate with the watch app and send information back and forth using the `WatchConnectivity Framework`.  I also have the app utilizing the `AlamoFire` framework to communicate with a server.

All my functions are being called and executing, however, i cant seem to get `print()` to log anything to the console!  I have tried placing various `print()` commands in different areas of the application, but none of them are producing anything to the console, even though the code around them is working.

I am 100% sure that I am looking at the correct area of XCode, I have gone to `View->Debug Area->Activate Console` and I have also made sure that `All output` is selected.  I even tried adding the `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` with its value as `disabled` but that didn't seem to do anything, either.

Here is an example of how I am using it in my `ViewController.swift` file:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("view did load")
    initWCSession()
    print("Attorney General Jeff Sessions")
}
```

This code runs and calls the `initWCSession()` function but I never see any output of `"view did load"` or `"Attorney General Jeff Sessions"` anywhere!

Is this is a bug in XCode? Is there something I am forgetting? (I am new to XCode).

Comment: Clear the filter on the console output.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov, I checked the filter and there are no filters :/

Comment: Try NSLog("test"). See the device logs at Xcode -> Window -> Devices.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov, that didn't work, either :/

Comment: Maybe the "Options" in the scheme has been changed? I'm talking about this: https://www.evernote.com/l/AOzBPBAfsTRPOLQ9Md2L6eQWfKoSpKFbLB8

Comment: @EricAya, interestingly, that menu looks different in this version of XCode.  I don't see the the radio buttons for `Console` under the `Queue Debugging` checkbox.  Could this option have been moved somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this worked but I went into `Edit Scheme` and checked the checkboxes for logging malloc.  I saved these settings and then went back into `Edit Scheme` and  unchecked the boxes and saved.

After that, I started seeing the print() statements log to the console!

Must be a bug in this version of XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Try view.backgroundColor = .red

I think view contoller is not being called. Just a guess. Otherwise printshould work.

Comment: I tried this code and when the app launches, the background of the view is red but i still dont see any output to the console.  I added that line of code directly after the first `print()`

Answer (score 0):

On the recent Xcode 11.3.1 I was getting the log lines from `CocoaLumberjack`, but nothing from my `print` calls. Restarting Xcode fixed the problem.